# Integration of android app with backend

Tags: android, json, web-services

i am developing an android app which i have to integrate with backend(developed in java and spring). Which will be the best way to integrate either WebServices or through http(JSON)..?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a JSON Response in Android/Java you need to do this:

1. Create a custom API Connector class
2. Declare a method that will return a JSON Array
3. Create a AsyncTask class (optional)
4. Decode JSONArray

   ```
   1.
   public class CustomAPIConnector {
   public final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/your-project-url/"; // 10.0.2.2 goes to computer localhost if you put localhost, it will go to the devices localhost which should not exist
   2.
   public JSONArray getUserInfo(String username, String password) {    

   HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
   // Add your POST variables to receive on your backend
   ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
   try {
       DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

       HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL + "login.php"); // have split up URL and page so you can redirect to different links easier if the URL changes
       httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


       HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
       httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   JSONArray jsonArray = null;
   if(httpEntity != null) {
       try {
           String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
           jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch(IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   return jsonArray;
   }
   }

   3.
   private class AvailableUser extends AsyncTask<ApiConnector,Boolean,JSONArray> {

   @Override
   protected JSONArray doInBackground(ApiConnector... params) {
       return params[0].availableUsername(etusername.getText().toString());
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
       checkAvailableUsername(jsonArray);
   }
   }

   private class AvailableEmail extends AsyncTask<ApiConnector,Boolean,JSONArray> {

   @Override
   protected JSONArray doInBackground(ApiConnector... params) {
       return params[0].availableEmail(etemail.getText().toString());
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
       checkAvailableEmail(jsonArray);
   }
   }
   4.
   private void checkAvailableEmail(JSONArray jsonArray) {
   String s = "";
   if(jsonArray != null) {
       for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
               JSONObject json = null;
           try {
               json = new JSONObject();
               json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
               if(!json.getString("count").isEmpty()) {
                   if(json.getString("count").equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                       status.setText("");
                       passedemail = true;
                       return;
                   } else {
                       status.setText("Email Taken");
                       passedemail = false;
                       return;
                   }
               }
           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       } 
   } else {
       status.setText("Failed - checkAvailableEmail");
   }
   }
   ```

**Please** note that this is actual code I have in one of my apps that registersa user, the getUserInfo gets all information from the user, and the Available email asynctask class is separate from the getUserInfo, it is the registering part, that checks if the email is available.

From here on, you can copy the code and change what you need to.

Comment: Thanks for your code I have implemented that... your code helped me while integration.... :)

Answer (score 0):

JSON  as name says java script object notation  would help you to exploit OOPS , POST/GET and js at backend . 
I use JSON ,  its easy to code , parse  and handle