# How to create a secure online database for android

Tags: android, mysql

I am developing an android application in which I need to store some of the information in an online database, probably MYSQL database. In app there is an account type i.e. a user logs in using his/her credentials. I want to add some security to the database i.e. If one user is connected using account A then no other person can use account A to access the database. How can I manage to add this type of security?

Comment: Are you accessing DB directly from android or using server scripts like PHP?

Comment: What is the best way to access? Directly using the app or Server scripts or PHP?

Comment: @priya - According to your scope plz go with server script. So you can implement user roles, Access controls, User sessions and so on..

Comment: I got you but I am a beginner right now. So do you have any tutorial for this or any thing related with server script so that I can follow it.

Comment: Sure, http://www.sitepoint.com/users-php-sessions-mysql/
http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/user-authentication/Jason_Gilmore05172011.php3
http://oreilly.com/catalog/webdbapps/chapter/ch08.html

you need to do lot of work with PHP. Any help you can email me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Rather use a database backend like a PHP application and built that securely.
In my experience it is much easier to work with the data on the PHP side.

[You can find the answer on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731755/integration-of-android-app-with-backend/24731973#24731973)